# Can't use result from subscribe angular

Tags: javascript, angular, components, observer-pattern, subscribe

I follow [this](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/) guide, and i try to do something similar at *Unrelated Components: Sharing Data with a Service* paragraph

**Data Service:**

```
 @Injectable()
export class MyDataService{

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    setInterval(() => { this.changeMessage(this.resultFromRestCall()); }, 10 * 1000);
  }

  changeMessage(message: object) {
    this.messageSource.next(message);
  }

  resultFromRestCall(){
    const json;
    this.http.get<object>(myApiUrl).subscribe(res => 
       json['data'] = res['data'] //this is an example
    );
    return json;
  }
```

**Component:**

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataservice: MyDataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataservice.currentMessage.subscribe(
      message => {this.handleVarChange(message); }
    );
  }

  handleVarChange(message) {
    console.log(message.data);
  }
```

- With this code i got "undefined" in `handleVarChange` log
- Instead of calling `this.handleVarChange(message);` in subscribe I write console.log(message) i got my result correctly.
- So, my question is if it's possible use the value coming from data service in some function of my component.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the `resultFromRestCall` method async?

Comment: It would be helpful, when you provide your `resultFromRestCall(...)` implementation.

Comment: how does your `message` look like exactly, you're not showing that... Could you create [mcve]

Comment: @Batajus I've updated my question with `resultFromRestCall()`  implementation.

Comment: @AJT_82 I assign value to json in subscription, I've update code, i miss it before.

Comment: Yaah, I saw that before you commented, so deleted message. But anyway, this is asynchronous, you are returning `json` before it has been populated, so it would be undefined yes.

Comment: There is a way to have sync call as 'async: false' in Ajax ?

Comment: No, but you can flip it around a bit, I'll write up an answer which hopefully works for you.

Comment: @AJT_82 ty very much

Comment: Updated answer, forgot to include the updated `resultFromRestCall` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With:

```
resultFromRestCall(){
  const json;
  this.http.get<object>(myApiUrl).subscribe(res => 
     // takes x amount of time to populate json
     json['data'] = res['data'] //this is an example
  );
 // executed instantly after above request has been called 
 return json;
}
```

You are returning `json` **before** it has been populated, since the request is asynchronous.

Instead you can flip it around a bit, and call `resultFromRestCall()` first, and when you get the response, **then** call `changeMessage()`:

```
setInterval(() => { 
  this.resultFromRestCall().subscribe((data) => {
    this.changeMessage(data);
  });
}, 10 * 1000);
```

where `resultFromRestCall` simply returns an observable:

```
resultFromRestCall(){
  return this.http.get<object>(myApiUrl);
}
```

Also remember to `clearInterval` in `OnDestroy`!

### [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ndbohj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Great, glad to hear! :)

Answer (score 0):

Omit the `.data` in `handleVarChange`:

Instead of

```
handleVarChange(message) {
  console.log(message.data);
}
```

write

```
handleVarChange(message) {
  console.log(message);
}
```

Comment: data is an array into my message, i have to access to it. If i log message in subscribe the data array is populated correctly. This is not the focus of the problem.